# Haskellのtype演算子に型シノニム以外の使い方はありますか？

Tags: haskell

最近Haskellの勉強を初めて，適当にライブラリを読んでいるのですが，type演算子の用途について疑問があります．

例えば，以下の例ですと右辺がなく，何のシノニムになっているのか分かりません．

https://github.com/RaphaelJ/friday/blob/master/src/Vision/Image/Class.hs#L93

```
class Storable (ImagePixel i) => MaskedImage i where
    type ImagePixel i
```

また，以下の例では，左辺 ImagePixel (Manifest p) のほうが，右辺 p よりも複雑になっていて，
シノニムを使う理由がよく分かりません．

https://github.com/RaphaelJ/friday/blob/master/src/Vision/Image/Type.hs#L52

```
instance Storable p => MaskedImage (Manifest p) where
    type ImagePixel (Manifest p) = p
```

type演算子には，型シノニム以外の使い方があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 6):

`class`や`instance`宣言中に現れる`type`や`data`は **Type Families（型族）** というGHC拡張で、トップレベルに現れる`type`とは少し異なる機能を提供しています。
型族を有効にするには、pragmaとして`TypeFamilies`を指定します（リンク先のソースコード先頭で宣言されています）。

Cf. https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-families.html

### 型関数

`class`宣言と`instance`宣言は普段の型クラス同様に対応しています。

普段、`class`宣言で「メソッド、その型、デフォルト実装」が与えられると思います。型族を用いると、言わばその「型レベル版」も宣言できる様になります。それが`type`を用いた型関数の宣言です。
つまりは「型関数、その種(kind)、デフォルト型」が定義できます。

その確認のため、trivialな例を出します:

```
class Hoge i where
    type Fuga i :: *         -- 種(kind)の明示
    type Fuga i = ()         -- デフォルト型

    piyo :: Fuga i -> Fuga i -- `Fuga i` の使用
    piyo = id                -- デフォルト実装

instance Hoge Int where
    type Fuga Int = Maybe Int
    piyo mn = fmap succ mn

instance Hoge Double where
    type Fuga Double = [Double]
    piyo ls = ls ++ ls
```

`piyo`がメソッドで、`Fuga`が型関数です。似た様に宣言できることが分かると思います。また、`Fuga i` を型として使うことも確認できます。

### 具体例

まず`class`宣言を見てみます:

```
class Storable (ImagePixel i) => MaskedImage i where
    type ImagePixel i
```

この宣言から分かることは、

- 型クラス`MaskedImage`を定義している
- `i`は`MaskedImage`のインスタンスを表す型変数
- `ImagePixel i`は`Storable`のインスタンスでなければならない
- `ImagePixel i`はinstance宣言で定義される型シノニム
- kindは省略されている
- デフォルト型は定義されていない

といったところでしょうか。
次に`instance`宣言を見てみます:

```
instance Storable p => MaskedImage (Manifest p) where
    type ImagePixel (Manifest p) = p
```

この`instance`宣言から分かることは、

- `Manifest p`は`MaskedImage`のインスタンス（たまたまインスタンスにも型変数`p`が含まれています）
- `ImagePixel (Manifest p)`は`p`の型シノニム
- `p`は`Storable`のインスタンスでなければならない

型チェックが通ればこの`instance`宣言はvalidと言えます。
ただ、`Storable p`についてもう少し説明が要るかもしれません。

### 確認

以下、この`instance`定義がvalidであることを簡単に確認します。

`Manifest p`を`MaskedImage`のインスタンスにするため、

- `class`を`instance`に書き換え
- `i`を`Manifest p`に機械的に置き換え

によって、以下が得られます:

```
instance Storable (ImagePixel (Manifest p)) => MaskedImage (Manifest p) where
    type ImagePixel (Manifest p)
```

ここで開発者は`ImagePixel (Manifest p)`は`p`の型シノニムであると定義したのでした:

```
instance Storable (ImagePixel (Manifest p)) => MaskedImage (Manifest p) where
    type ImagePixel (Manifest p) = p
```

この型シノニムの定義通り、`ImagePixel (Manifest p)`は`p`に置き換えられるため、以下が得られます:

```
instance Storable p => MaskedImage (Manifest p) where
    type ImagePixel (Manifest p) = p
```